# Custom Sharepoint solution: problems when adding content type column

Tags: content-type, site-column, feature-upgrade

We've developed a custom Sharepoint feature with custom site column and custom content type. We have no problems in production environment, but we're facing a problem in next development steps and releases: 
when there's the need to add a new Site column to an existing content type, I cannot manage to propagate the changes to the subsites. I see the new column in the root site, I see the content type in the root site with the new column, but in the lists in the subsites using that content type I always see the content type without the new column. No idea what to do here: the only thing that work is adding manually the column to the content type for each list using it: time consuming, and the column is added for EVERY content type in the list, not only the custom one.

Please advice

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: You should take a look at MS recommendations regarding updating content types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442695(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've found a method to check for the content type available link fields and update it in all subsites, matching the one in the root site.

Hope it helps

```
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Processing web {0}",web.Url);
    try
    {
        //Gets page list
        SPList page = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.ListName.News);
        SPFieldCollection webFields = web.Fields;
        SPContentType webContentType = page.ContentTypes[Constants.ContentType.NewsCTName];

        if (webContentType != null)
        {
            foreach (SPField field in rootContentType.Fields)
            {
                if (!webContentType.Fields.ContainsField(field.InternalName))
                {
                    SPFieldLink link = new SPFieldLink(field);
                    webContentType.FieldLinks.Add(link);
                    webContentType.Update();

                    System.Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Added {0} to {1}", field.InternalName, web.Url);
                    System.Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        web.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        System.Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```